# Using BeautifulSoup to retrieve information based on the attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<resultsummary>
    <resultticker category="executed">
        <count>12</count>
        <percentage>1.0</percentage>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
    </resultticker>
    <resultticker category="done">
        <count>16</count>
        <percentage>0.6</percentage>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
    </resultticker>
</resultsummary>
```

I am using `BeatifulSoup4` and I get the response above using the command `soup.find("resultsummary")`.
What I want to do is, I want to retrieve the `count` that is in the `resultticker` tag and categorized them by the `category` attribute.

So, I would want to get, `{ executed: 12, done: 16 }`.

I tried to do `soup.find("resultsummary").find('resultticker')['category']` something like this, but it just gives me the name of the attribute `executed` but not the information inside the tag.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you pointing to the resultticker attribute, if you want to get the value inside it maybe point to it `soup.find("resultsummary").find('resultticker').find('count')`

Comment: Maybe this: `soup.find("resultticker", {"category": "executed"})` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div>
    <resultsummary>
    <resultticker category="executed">
        <count>12</count>
        <percentage>1.0</percentage>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
    </resultticker>
    <resultticker category="done">
        <count>16</count>
        <percentage>0.6</percentage>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
        <id xlink:href="...">id_num</id>
    </resultticker>
</resultsummary>
</div>"""

result = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for resultticker in soup.find("resultsummary").find_all('resultticker'):  #iterate each resultticker 
    result[resultticker['category']] = resultticker.count.text  #Key=category & Value=count
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'executed': '12', 'done': '16'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
final = {}
for rt in soup.findAll('resultticker'):
    final[rt["category"]] = rt.count.text
```

---

```
{'executed': '12', 'done': '16'}
```

---

[Live Python Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/90e5405856)